Shrinkwrap artifacts
Tried everything (i think), yet i cannot find the way to get rid of these artifacts.
Did retopo after sculpting then add multisurface and shrinkwrap modifier. The retopo base mesh seems clean to me (attached pics). No overlapping vertices/faces/edges so i just dont understand. Thank You.
EDIT: Ok i found overlapping faces on the neck and at the front of the ear, but for top-ear part yet i could not found the cause.



can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

@HarryMcKenzie thank you Harry but already found the solution, i'm gonna answer my question soon.

That part is a bit special because the shape of the ear. In this case the faces of the base/retopo mesh getting closer to the inner parts of the target mesh and somehow shrinkwrap prefers to stick to these faces instead of the outter ones.
The base/retopo mesh needs some extra/more geometry there so the base mesh can follow the outter parts of the target mesh better and can help shrinkwrap do it's job.

The base mesh (blue line) 'sink' too much into the target mesh, getting closer to the ear's inner facces (dense red lines). You should add some geometry (green line).
